# How to name an array based on a variable name

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

Working is:

```
foreach (string feature in alpha)
            {
                for (int i=0; i < l.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (l[i] == feature)
                    {
                        string[] ("{0}",feature) = new string[];
                    }
                }
            }
```

`string[] ("{0}",feature) = new string[];` is incorrect. What needs to be done is, whenever there is a match for the condition `(l[i] == feature)` , create a new string array as: `string[] (whatever string there is in feature) = new string[]`.

Possible?

Comment: Not possible like that, please explain why you are trying to do this?

Comment: We need more information, but you probably want a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, where the key is `feature`

Comment: @weston because `alpha` is an Array and for each element in `alpha`, a text file is enumerated and if a match is found, a new array is desired to be created and all the sub-values for the match are needed to be inserted into that array. This operation needs to be done on each element in `alpha`. Hence a new Array needs to be created for almost each element in `alpha`. I want to automate this process of naming Arrays. Possible?

Comment: @KooKiz, Thanks. I assume `string` is the key in `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`?

Comment: @RehanKhan Yes. You can then access it like `dictionary[feature] = ...`

Comment: @KooKiz Sorry. Did you mean `dictionary["feature"]` if `feature` is defined as `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a dictionary is what you want.

```
var arrays = alpha
               .Where(a => l.Contains(a))
               .ToDictionary(a => a, a => new List<string>());
```

Then to access one:

```
List<string> array = arrays["somefeature"];
```

Also stop using arrays, there's almost no good reason to choose them over the other collection types. I have used `List` because you said you want to append to it.

Comment: Thank you. How to use `List` for creating tabular form of data i.e., horizontal and vertical directions?

Comment: Well the dictionary is that, the key is one dimension and the value, the list, is the other. If that's not good enough, then you need to ask another  question.

Comment: Indeed it is. Thanks a lot for all the guidances.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sorted list where the key value would be your feature;

```
        var featureList = new SortedList<string, string[]>();

        foreach (string feature in alpha)
        {
            var matchingFeatures = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < l.Length; i++)
            {
                if (l[i] == feature)
                {
                    matchingFeatures.Add(l[i]);
                }
            }
            featureList.Add(feature, matchingFeatures.ToArray());
        }
```